# magento checkout page different template

Tags: magento, templating

I have to have totally new template for checkout page alone in magento. In case of ***cms/catalog/category pages*** we can have customized templates from back-end.

But fro how we can have different templates for different modules in magento. I tried with different **root template** but still i wil have many problems from the existing css/js. SO i want to have totally new template for checkout module alone.

Did any one tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be a case of assigning a specific template file to the checkout pages in the XML files, I can't remember what one though off the top of my head.

Comment: I guess i have not asked it in the right way. I need to update have different theme like frontend/default/theme1 and frontend/default/theme2 (not just template like 1column or 2 column-left) for two diffrent modules. To be simple how to set theme name from xml file/controller file